# Java correct way to process graphics

Tags: java, graphics2d

I'm currently working on a game with simple 2d Graphics, but I'm looking for the correct way to do so...I've heard a lot of ways to go about displaying graphics and just want some things to be cleared up, and if possible could I get a example of how to correctly display graphics.

First, is overriding the paint method correct?

Second, is calling the repaint method correct?

Comment: Q: Java correct way to process graphics? A: Don't use Java :P - What libraries are you using/want to use/can use? Welcome to SO BTW!

Comment: I would be willing to use some libraries what do you suggest?

Comment: You wont get very far without using libraries? Do you have any code to show us what you're trying to do? Also put "@AlecTeal" in your message so I get notified when you respond, I don't have to here because I'm responding to your post, so you will get a notification

Comment: Start by taking a lok at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

Comment: You could try javaFx. That's the latest trend in java graphics))